# One route for multiple action( difference name, http verb) in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create one route for different actions for example: 
http://www.example.com/Students

I have some action in StudentController:

```
[HttpDelete]
public Student DeleteStudent(int id)

[HttpPost]
public int AddStudent(StudentInfo student)

[HttpPut]
public bool UpdateStudent(StudentInfo student)
```

I want to create a route which determine what action will be called based on Http method of request.

So when user call http://www.example.com/Students  by Post method, It will be AddStudent

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  // Get:
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Students()
{
    // do some stuff
    return View();
}

// Post:
[ActionName("Students")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Students_Post()
{
    // do some stuff
    return View();
}
```